# How to Customize Odoo Inventory Adjustment for Single Journal Entry on Multiple Product Adjustments?

Tags: odoo-15

In Odoo's 15 version inventory adjustment, when adjusting a single product, it typically results in one stock move and one associated journal entry being created. However, when adjusting multiple products simultaneously, it often leads to individual stock moves for each product, while a single journal entry encompasses all the adjustments made. Is this behavior possible to modify in Odoo?